# OpenCV - Ellipse not showing at all

Tags: java, opencv

I wanna make an ellipse mask for cropping an image so only the contents inside of the ellipse will be shown.

Could you inspect my code?

```
public static Mat cropImage(Mat imageOrig, MatOfPoint contour){
    Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour);

    MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f(contour.toArray());
    RotatedRect boundElps = Imgproc.fitEllipse(contour2f);

    Mat out = imageOrig.submat(rect);

    // the line function is working
    Imgproc.line(out, new Point(0,0), new Point(out.width(), out.height()), new Scalar(0,0,255), 5);

    // but not this one
    Imgproc.ellipse(out, boundElps, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 99);

    return out;
}//cropImage
```

It seems like it's not working at all. Though you can see the line function I've done to test if it is working on the right image and I can see a line but there's no ellipse.

Here's a sample output of my cropImage function.

[image: cropImage's Output]

TIA

Comment: Don't crop the image. You're retrieving the ellipse coordinates in the `imageOrig` coordinates system. If you want to show the ellipse on the crop, you need to translate the ellipse center, something like: `boundElps.center().x -= rect.x; boundElps.center().y -= rect.y;`

Comment: Hey @Miki you should make this the answer! That solved my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're retrieving the ellipse coordinates in the `imageOrig` coordinates system, but you're showing it on the cropped `out` image.

If you want to show the ellipse on the crop, you need to translate the ellipse center to account for the translation introduced by the crop (top-left coordinates of `rect`), something like:

```
boundElps.center().x -= rect.x; boundElps.center().y -= rect.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
RotatedRect rRect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(contour2f);
Imgproc.ellipse(out, rRect , new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);
```

Comment: It must work, you change the thickness and try again

Comment: I already changed the thickness around 2-20 and I still haven't got anything. :(

Comment: So the problem maybe with the points, because you cropped the image, the coordination is not the same. If you draw it on the same image (with crop) then it will be OK. You can try it.

Comment: So the problem maybe with the points, because you cropped the image, the coordination is not the same. If you draw it on the original image (without crop) then it will be OK. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for the minimum requirements for using the fitEllipse as shown in [this post](http://blog.christianperone.com/2014/06/simple-and-effective-coin-segmentation-using-python-and-opencv/). 
The function `fitEllipse` requires atleast 5 points.
Note: Although the reference I mention is for Python, I hope you can do the same for Java.

```
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    # Probably this can help but not required 
    if area < 2000 or area > 4000:
         continue
    # This is the check I'm referring to
    if len(cnt) < 5:
         continue
    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
    cv2.ellipse(roi, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think if the points is not greater than 5 I would have an error right? I have encountered this before and I think I've already filtered all contours that has less than 5. Thanks!

Comment: And I would say you should draw the ellipse in the original image, not on the cropped image. I guess you are doing that. `Imgproc.ellipse(imgOrig, boundElps, new Scalar (0,255,0), 2)` should work. Otherwise, change the coordinates to the local coordinate system